# How to Change URL using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**Original URL**
http://localhost/admin/url/friends.php?user=hello&id=123

**I want the URL to look like this:**
http://localhost/admin/url/friends/hello/123

---

I have use for first Perameter, but how can i use for second perameter too...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule friends/(.*)/ friends.php?u=$1
RewriteRule friends/(.*) friends.php?u=$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule friends/(.*)/([0-9]+) friends.php?u=$1&id=$2
```

You can number the parameters and use them in the order of the number.